# Difficulty with Milnor number

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

I am reading through the wikipedia page of [Milnor number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milnor_number#Examples).

I am reading [example 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milnor_number#2) where they calculate the Milnor number of $f(x,y)=x^3+xy^2$. So if we calculate the partial derivatives we obtain $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2+y^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2xy$, so we have that $$\mu (f)=\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/(3x^2+y^2,xy)$$

But if I look at this, it seems to me that we have a generating set $\{1,x,y,x^2\}$, but the basis should consist of infinitely many monomials, since we cannot write for example $x^n$ for $n>2$ as a linear combination of the above monomials. But wikipedia claims that $\mu(f)=4$.

My question: what am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: With your particular example: $x^n = x^n - \left(x^n+\frac{y^2x^{n-2}}{3}\right) = -\frac{y^2x^{n-2}}{3} = 0$ when $n > 2$. A similar calculation eliminates $y^n$ for $n>2$ (different constant, but that won't matter). All of the $x^iy^j$ for $i,j > 1$ are out, which leaves only the given generating set.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Ah I see, thanks for the clarification